# How to disable netty logs programmatically using log4j2

Tags: java, netty, log4j2

How to disable netty logs programmatically using log4j2 while using AsyncHttpClient from ning.com libraray.I have tried below code but not working.

I have tried below code

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.setLevel(LogManager.getLogger("io.netty").getName(),org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.INFO);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to change the log level of a particular logger. If that is what you need to do you can use code like this:

```
    LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
    LoggerConfig loggerCfg = config.getLoggerConfig("io.netty");
    loggerCfg.setLevel(Level.OFF); //Using this level disables the logger.
    ctx.updateLoggers();
```

Comment: Ok set the level to OFF

Comment: How is your method to different to `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("someLogger").setLevel(Level.OFF)`?